# output JSON values to text view without using listview

Tags: android, json, listview

i have this code here, and it's working VERY fine.

i try to display the results of the JSON into a textView but everytime i do it, the app crash and i search a lot about that,

Most of solutions is about using values with ListView BUT i only need one result and that is what im retrieving from JSON

```
public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_profile_activity);
        // we will using AsyncTask during parsing 
        new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
    }

 // you can make this class as another java file so it will be separated from your main activity.
    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

        // set your json string url here
        String yourJsonStringUrl = "http://example.com";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {

                // instantiate our json parser
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // get json string from url
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

                // get the array of users
                dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("Users");

                // loop through all users
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);


                    String username = c.getString("UserName");

                    // show the values in our logcat
                    Log.e(TAG, "Username: " +  username);

                    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                    lblName.setText(username);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {}
    }
}
```

Json Values

```
{ "Users": [ { "fullName    ":"", "UserName ":"admin", "UserRegistered  ":"2014-09-07 15:42:39", "EmailAddress  ":"usf.me2000@gmail.com", "ProfilePicture ":"http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/8f5b41b43c804b25b9bed0806b82ac69.gif", "Facebook  ":"http://facebook.com", "Twitter   ":"http://twitter.com", "LinkedIn   ":"http://plus.google.com", "GooglePlus ":"http://linkedin.com", "ProfileHeader ":"User Extra Field", "TotalPosts   ":"10" } ] }
```

LogCat Error

```
09-08 17:19:56.426: E/AsyncTaskParseJson.java(6729): Username: admin // This to validate the getting value is correct


09-08 17:19:56.430: W/dalvikvm(6729): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa624a288)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10250)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10205)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6296)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3547)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at com.twaa9l.photosee.ProfileActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(ProfileActivity.java:67)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at com.twaa9l.photosee.ProfileActivity$AsyncTaskParseJson.doInBackground(ProfileActivity.java:1)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-08 17:19:56.430: E/AndroidRuntime(6729):     ... 5 more
```

Comment: wheres the `textView` ? assuming you are using the parameter `strFromDoInBg` in `onPostExecute` it will always returns `null` because your `doInBackground` returns `null`.

Comment: @Spurdow in the layout file, i try a lot of solutions and didn't work for me so i post the code as it is if anyone know how to solve it.

Comment: Could you provide the log of your crash please?

Comment: mean you want to show whole JSONResponse in the TextView.?

Comment: The keys you used in your getString statements doesn't match your json data keys? For example, I don't see a "firstname" key in your json data...

Comment: Like @Spurdow says, where did you set the result of your JSon request into the TextView?

Comment: @grattmandu03 i updated the Full Code with CatLog

Comment: @SilentKiller  i updated the Full Code with CatLog

Comment: @alpinescrambler i updated the Full Code with CatLog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LogCat says it all. You cannot update the textview in doInBackground. Do the updating in onPostExecute

Comment: i try to do this inside the onPostExcute `TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            lblName.setText(username);` but i get error inside eclipse

Comment: success, i put `public String username;` before the onCreate and i insert this inside the onPostExecute `TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            lblName.setText(username);` and removed the String word from the here `String username = c.getString("UserName");` and now it's working like charm

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `getString` "firstname" and "lastname", but your json data doesn't have those  keys.

Comment: The log indicates that you're referencing the wrong view. My guess is it has something to do with `TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);`. It probably has to do with the fact that your background class does not reference the layout file.

Comment: i don't think so because i moved the code `TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        lblName.setText("Hello");` inside the `onCreate` and run it again and it's working fine without crashing showing hello word inside the textView

Comment: Right, because `setContentView(R.layout.view_profile_activity);` is inside `onCreate` but your background class does not set a view.